# Why constructor needed in es6?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, enzyme

Why when I write 'new ServerNotificationApi'  in test id does not call constructor, for me `new ServerNotificationApi.constructor()` works, but I can not understand why when I write   `new ServerNotificationApi` I got an error in unit test 'TypeError: _serverNotifications.default is not a constructor'

class

```
class ServerNotificationApi {
        constructor() {
            SignalR.initConnection(url.serverNotificationHubName)
        }

        subscribe = callback => SignalR.subscribe(url.entityChanged, url.serverNotificationHubName, callback);

        unsubscribe = callback => SignalR.unsubscribe(url.entityChanged, url.serverNotificationHubName, callback);
    }

    export default new ServerNotificationApi()
```

test

```
 it('constructor should call signalR method \'initConnection\'', () => {
        sinon.stub(SignalR, 'initConnection')

        new ServerNotificationApi.constructor()

    SignalR.initConnection.calledWith(url.serverNotificationHubName).should.be.true

        SignalR.initConnection.restore()
    })
```

Answer (score 6):

```
export default new ServerNotificationApi()
               ↑↑↑
```

You are exporting an *instance* of the class, not the class itself. You're essentially doing:

```
let foo = new ServerNotificationApi();
new foo();
```

Which, yeah, doesn't work. Get rid of the `new` in `export`.